# How to create an interactive image panning in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm kinda new in flash and as3 so this may not be as difficult as it looks right now.
I've been trying to figure out how I can pan an image in flash (x and y). I have a movieclip and I want the user only to see a small part as he's panning with the mouse. 
Hope you can help me out with this.

Thanks,

Joana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this: http://as3imagepan.blogspot.com/
and download the fla's here: http://www.flashmadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/panning_image.zip

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
var bitmapHolder:Sprite // this is your image container
var masker:Sprite = new Sprite();
masker.graphics.beginFill(0);
masker.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width_you_want_visible, height_you_want_visible);
masker.graphics.endFill();

bitmapHolder.mask = masker;
addChild(bitmapHolder);
addChild(masker);

bitmapHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);

function startDragging(e:MouseEvent):void {
 bitmapHolder.startDrag();
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
}

function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent):void {
 stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
 bitmapHolder.stopDrag();
}
```